# Automatically change Gmail signature by recipient

Tags: email, automation, gmail

Is there a Chrome extension or Gmail plugin to automatically change/adjust the Gmail signature by the emails recipient? I'm thinking of adjustable rules or a plugin for the Gmail web client.

For example:

I'm preparing a mail for adam@example.com. Normally it would add my standard signature "Best, Devan", but because I created a rule for adam@example.com Gmail sees that the email is addressed at adam@example.com and automatically changes the signature that is added to the email footer to "Sincerely, Devan Loper".

Comment: Related: [Assign a signature per contact in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39714/74948)